# Handling sub domains with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm currently working on a web application in java that is built with Spring and i want subdomains for it. I currently have a VPS and a domain and i have a A record that forwards all subdomains to my VPS ip where my Spring application is. I've tried many solutions online but non seem to work [Failed Solution](https://www.schakko.de/2020/06/04/handling-subdomains-in-multi-tenant-applications-with-spring-boot-web-mvc/). I tried the solution above with some modifications and it still did not work.

Comment: it didnt work..

Comment: Ok, but then if you're going to link to a failed solution, you need to add a description of that proposed solution directly into the question, and also explain how it failed to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it and added some modifications but it just simply wouldn't do what it said it would. I've tried to make my self and also tried other solutions online just nothing works.